# how to enter the BIOS menu on a very fast computer

Tags: windows, bios, usb-flash-drive

I want to access the BIOS menu so I can boot up a USB drive containing a windows 7 installation ISO.

The problem being that the device started booting up way too fast all of a sudden.

I tried mashing the designated key (F2) very fast but I still couldnt access the BIOS

I also made multiple tries with the other key (del) and it still didnt work

I tried holding down the buttons when the restarting started but it didnt work either

I tried shutting down and then turning the machine on instead of restarting but it didn't work

I tried booting into safe mode (from msconfig.exe) and still no luck

what can I do ?

Comment: unplug you boot disk is one option. then it should give you plenty of time.

Comment: Thanks, can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Try pressing F8 while booting

Comment: Pressing F8 didnt work

Comment: The first thing I would try is a different keyboard, or plugging the existing keyboard into a different port. The keys for setup or boot menu vary.  Many times, a boot menu option is F12.  

If you're comfortable working inside the computer, many bios will prompt to enter setup if the amount of ram changes. Adding or removing a stick might work.

Comment: If you open the case, and unplug the sata or power line to the hard disk you boot from, your BIOS won;t be able to boot, and will usually prompt you to enter setup. it can't move forward, so it should display for as long as you need it to. after configuring the bios, power off, plug the drive back in, and boot back up .

Comment: If you're using a USB keyboard, make sure it's plugged into one of the motherboard's primary USB ports connected to the chipset, not an auxiliary USB port connected to a separate controller.

Answer (score 4):

Your USB keyboard may be unable to connect on that particular port.  On my Dells, I note that the USB3 ports are NOT available for BIOS, so I plug my keyboards into USB2.  Similarly, some keyboards take multiple seconds to initialize, so try a different keyboard.

Find out your computer's motherboard, and edit the question with it.  Google for that motherboard's BIOS hotkey (might be Del, Esc, F2, F12, etc).

Sometimes, BIOS is available for a longer time for hotkey when you've fully shut down the PC, and started cold. (That is, reboot is fast and avoids the BIOS delay).

MSConfig happens after BIOS.  Windows restart settings happen after BIOS.

Finally, when you successfully get into the BIOS, search around for a "BIOS delay" or "Pause before" boot setting.